# what is missing in SQL Server Express 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

i want to install my client an application that uses SQL Server 2008 database.
i thought of installing SQL Server 2008 Express R2 instead and to save him some money.
i read all about SQL Server 2008 express R2 version and i found this information:

•   No limitation on the number of user connections to the DB.

•   16 instances but No limitation on number of DBs

- 1GB RAM

•   10GB space for R2 and 4G for the 2008 express (not R2)

•   Constrained to a single CPU

but then my friend said it also missing many basic management tools and other features like for example:

No buckuping option? 
No jobs?

can you tell me what is MISSING in SQL Server Express 2008 ?
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) is the Edition matrix that shows what you have in Express versus one of the higher editions.

Your friend is a little miss informed. You can download the [SQL Express 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23650) with the Management Tools, the link is under the "Instructions" section of the download page. Express edition does not include SQL Agent service which is used for automating SQL Server task, but you can use SQLCMD and Scheduled Task within Windows as a viable option. You can still backup a database and restore the database.